# How can I fix this lighting bug in Unreal Engine 5?

Tags: rendering, lumen, shadow, lighting, unreal-engine5

There's not much to say, the lighting just looks hideous and I have no idea why. I didn't change any light settings. It looks like a wood texture but it's all white (supposed to be).

I'm using UE5.1 and I'm a beginner, but I have prior experience with Unity and coding in general, but this, this I don't understand at all.

When you move around, the lighting glitches even more. You can see what I mean in [this video.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l9jxfffy5fefh00oPrX7SjKXattabLGU/view?usp=sharing)

Can someone tell me what's going on and how I can fix it?
[image: There are these weird white lines.]
[image: The shadows are way too dark as you can see, even though the picture before it looked fine-ish.]
[image: You can see them better here]
[image: Pitch black]
[image: This is from far, and you can see the sun, the direction where the light is coming from.]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should probably be migrated to another StackExchange site like [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) or removed, because it is not related to programming. It is probably even better suited for a specific [Unreal Engine discussion board](https://forums.unrealengine.com/).

Comment: Oh alright, my bad i'll remove it didn't know, thanks for the help though.
Edit: Oh wait no never mind if it'll get migrated that's fine with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I don't know what happened but it's fixed now.

The engine crashed at one point and when I opened it back up again the lighting looks great.

I'm sorry if anyone comes across this hoping they would find an answer.
Just know your problem might solve itself. Sit back, grab some popcorn, watch a movie, take a break. You need it.

Nothing lasts forever, you will come across a solution soon, just be patient.

Edit: After more experimentation, it happens whenever I have a mesh with physics activated. I think it probably has to do with my outdated graphics card since this isn't the only lighting glitch I've had to deal with.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).